# Apply infinite scroll to JSON array in ionic-3 app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How can I implement infinite scroll to my JSON array? I want to display only 5 items initially.

```
data:[
0: Object { id: 123, title: "New family member Khjkjh has joined mymily", mm_family_id: 122, … }
1: Object { id: 124, title: "New family member Hey Dau has joined mymily", mm_family_id: 122, … }
2: Object { id: 125, title: "New family member Hey Dau has joined mymily", mm_family_id: 122, … }
3: Object { id: 126, title: "New family member New Dau has joined mymily", mm_family_id: 122, … }
4: Object { id: 127, title: "New family member New Dau has joined mymily", mm_family_id: 122, … }
5: Object { id: 128, title: "New family member New Dau has joined mymily", mm_family_id: 122, … }
6: Object { id: 129, title: "New family member New Dau has joined mymily", mm_family_id: 122, … }
7: Object { id: 130, title: "Abhishek Pandey has commented on post", mm_family_id: 122, … }
8: Object { id: 131, title: "Abhishek Pandey has commented on post", mm_family_id: 122, … }
]
```

Ionic info

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v8.7.0
npm  : 5.6.0
OS   : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [infinite scroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/) feature of ionic and can initialize your items array inside constructor with the number of items you want to display at first in your case 5 items at start so you can do this:

your html:

```
<ion-content>
 <ion-list>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let i of items">{{i}}</ion-item>
 </ion-list>

 <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
   <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
 </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

in your ts:

```
items = [];
count: number = 0;

constructor() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  // here you can limit the items according to your needs.
    this.items.push(data[this.count]);   // your JSON data which you want to display
    this.count++ //i am using a count variable to keep track of inserted records to avoid inserting duplicate records on infinite scroll
  }
}

doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
      this.items.push(data[this.count]); // this will start pushing next 5 items
      this.count++
    }

    infiniteScroll.complete();
  }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. but there is some issue while loading more data same data will push into the array when JSON data reach the end.

Comment: In the for loop of `doInfinite` there, he forgot to increase the `this.count` variable. If you add this, it should work.

Comment: oops sorry just went unnoticed thanks @StephanStrate..wait will update the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use the slice pipe with your ngFor. (Credits to https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-implement-ionic-infinite-scroll-to-show-my-array-data/96860/5)

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let i of items  | slice:0:slice">
    your code here
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px" (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
  <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data...">
  </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

in your .ts file:

```
slice: number = 5;
doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
 setTimeout(() => {
  this.slice += 5;
  infiniteScroll.complete();
 }, 300);
}
```

In the first iteration, you will show the first 5 items (slice = 5). When doInfinite is called, your slice increases its value in 5, so you will show 10 items.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: infiniteScroll.target.complete();  this is how you need to call in ionic v4 and v5